# How can I make Windows beep when pyinstaller is finished running?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Good morning!

I'm currently trying to work on making an executable for my Python script using PyInstaller and so I often have to wait for it to finish compiling (is that the right word in this case?), but I don't want to keep staring at the screen unnecessarily.

I understand that I can import winsound and make it beep that way from within a script, but how would I do so with pyinstaller from terminal?

In other words, whenever I type in "pyinstaller myScript.py" into terminal and Python finishes creating the executable, I'd like Windows to beep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply run it sequentially after the pyinstaller program: `pyinstaller myScript.py; python3 -c "print('\7')";`

You can also try `pyinstaller myScript.py; echo ^G;`. Where ^G is the character that is printed when you do `Ctrl` + `G` on your keyboard.

Using `winsound`, you could have a simple python script that beeps:

`beep.py`

```
import winsound 
              
winsound.Beep(500, 250) # Hz, ms
```

then in your terminal:
pyinstaller myScript.py; python3 beep.py`

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately =( no beep. Did you put quotation marks around the print statement on purpose?

Comment: See edit, you could try echoing this character to a file to be able to reuse it later.

Comment: That didn't work either =(
I'm not sure what "echo ^G" does exactly... when I do ^G I just get a colon. Is this supposed to produce a beep sound?

Comment: Pressing and holding the `Ctrl` key then pressing the `G` key should print `^G`. It does for me in Windows 10 Command Prompt.

Comment: Thank you for all your help so far!
When I run the script alone, the computer beeps, but trying "python3 beep.py" runs successfuly but does not return a beep... I am on python 3.9.2 so it should work

Comment: I got it!! I just used "; python beep.py" at the end, without the 3. Thank you very much for your help =)